# custom layout in form views in Odoo 14

Tags: odoo-14

I need a form view and I need its layout to be customized, using directly the Bootstrap 4 styles

How exactly can I do that ?

Also

I need some fields/tabs to appear conditionally (if some values is true) and such conditionally appearing fields need to be in my custom layout

Is this possible ?

How ?

First of all, I could use an example of a custom layout

And then I could use some enlightenment on how the conditional appearing of fields is done, behind the scenes

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a form view using any html you like. You can also use `xpath` to load custom css and javascript, such as bootstrap. You should load the xpath straight after your opening form tag.

```xml
<xpath expr="." position="inside">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</xpath>
```

There a couple of ways to show things conditionally. I find the following example easiest when using the form views:

```xml
<div id="my-div" attrs="{'invisible': [('field','==',True)]}">Do not show this text if the field is true</div>
```